# Facebook Graph API Call - Feed is not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am trying to make a graph api call to post status update to a fan pages.

I am using http post here
my base url: https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed

message=hi&access_token={access_token}

I am however getting an error

{"error":{"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","type":"OAuthException","code":2}}

Could you tell me if I am missing anything?

Things I checked:

1. Access token is valid
2. Page exisits

Comment: Are you trying to post a status update or getting all the past status updates? The first one should be a POST request, the second, a GET request

Comment: I am trying to POST. I have mentioned that in my message. I am trying an http post here.

Comment: You said "to obtain the status updates for fan pages" in the first line. Can you update your question and give the exact `curl` request minus your access token?

Comment: Have updated. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a genuine bug at Fb's end.

Answer (score 0):

You need the **extended permission** `manage_pages` for your app (or through graph explorer) to be able to publish to the page feed. Once you have a new access_token with that permission, this should work:

```
curl \
  -F "message=hi" \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/<page_id>/feed"
```

Or whatever method you prefer.

*Edit*: You may also need the page access token, as described in the [Publish page API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/#publish)

Comment: How do I get the extended permission manage_pages?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens - follow the link for extended access permissions

Comment: I added the manage_pages permission for the user/app. I obtained the new access token and have also exchanged it for a long-lived access token. 
I am still seeing this issue.
I am the admin of the page and I am trying to post to the page, when I am getting this error.

Comment: Did you try using the Graph API Explorer?